# Automated script to change page encoding after page has been downloaded in Google Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, automation, encoding, character-encoding

guys!
My Chrome doesn't properly recognize page encoding of our local TWIKI site.
So, every time i enter the site i have to set suitable encoding manually (Settings -> Tools -> Encoding -> Cyrillic (Windows-1251)).
I think that the problem could be solved by creating the special script which will change page encoding after site will have downloaded. 
The problem is i haven't found appropriate script & i don't have mind how to code it.
Could you give me right advise in my question?
Or i got a wrong way in solving this problem and there are some more suitable decisions of my problem...

Answer (score 0):

You got a wrong way in solving the problem. The solution is to make the server send an appropriate Content-Type header that announces the correct encoding. The methods for this depend on server-side software used. If the server does not announce any encoding, and it cannot easily be made to do that, you can use the `<meta charset=windows-1251>` tag in the `head` element of the document.

Chrome is quite capable of recognizing the encoding, when it has been announced properly, by the protocols.

Comment: Server sends such string '<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ru_RU.cp1251" />'. Maybe the problem in 'ru_RU.cp1251' isn't appropriate character name?

Comment: Right, it’s not a registered charset name and generally not recognized by browsers. In the official registry http://www.iana.org/assignments/character-sets/ the name is windows-1251, with no aliases (though cp1251 or cp-1251 might be in some use in practice). The name `ru_RU.cp1251` looks like a locale name. Charset names do not encode country or language information, just the character encoding.